# Android DOM Parser - retrieving image link from description tag

Tags: android, xml, parsing, dom

I'm using DOM Parser to parse this XML feed: http://loc.grupolusofona.pt/index.php/?format=feed

I got the Parser working fine for all tags, i'm just missing ideas to be able to retrieve the image from within the description tag.

The description tag on the feed looks like this:

```
<description><![CDATA[<div class="K2FeedIntroText"><p><img style="margin: 10px;"
alt="joana soares rostos" src="http://loc.grupolusofona.pt/images/stories/varios/joana%20soares%20rostos.jpg"
height="110" width="120" />Quis ser veterinária mas deixou-se seduzir pela magia
de retratar o real. Joana Soares frequenta o primeiro ano do curso de Fotografia
da Lusófona e descreve a sua paixão pelas fotos como «inexplicável».</p>
</div>]]></description>
```

And i wanted to retrieve the image link:

```
http://loc.grupolusofona.pt/images/stories/varios/joana%20soares%20rostos.jpg
```

My Parser :

```
public class XMLParser {

// constructor
public XMLParser() {

}

/**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

/**
 * Getting XML DOM element
 * @param XML string
 * */
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}

/** Getting node value
  * @param elem element
  */
 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {

     if( elem != null){
         return elem.getTextContent();
             }


     return "";
 }

 /**
  * Getting node value
  * @param Element node
  * @param key string
  * */
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
}
```

And my Main Activity:

```
public class Noticias extends ListActivity {

// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://loc.grupolusofona.pt/index.php/?format=feed";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
static final String KEY_LINK = "link";
static final String KEY_PUBDATE = "pubDate";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_noticias);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Spanned>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Spanned>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, Spanned> map = new HashMap<String, Spanned>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, Html.fromHtml(parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID)));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, Html.fromHtml(parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE)));
        map.put(KEY_DESC, Html.fromHtml(parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC)));
        map.put(KEY_PUBDATE, Html.fromHtml(parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUBDATE)));
        map.put(KEY_LINK, Html.fromHtml(parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK)));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
            R.layout.linha_feed,
            new String[] { KEY_TITLE, KEY_DESC, KEY_PUBDATE, KEY_LINK }, new int[] {
                    R.id.title, R.id.desc, R.id.pub, R.id.link});

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem

            String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc)).getText().toString();
            String pub = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pub)).getText().toString();
            String link = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.link)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent

            System.out.println("Title: " + title);
            System.out.println("Link: " + link);
            System.out.println("Description:" + description);
            System.out.println("Pubdate: " + pub);

            Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            in.setData(Uri.parse(link));

            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
}
}
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RegEx` with a simple pattern like this:

```
<\s*img\s*[^>]+src\s*=\s*(['"]?)(.*?)\1
```

Here use these functions:

```java
public static String getMatch(String patternString, String text, int groupIndex){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL );
    return RegEx.getMatch(pattern, text, groupIndex);
}

public static String getMatch(Pattern pattern, String text, int groupIndex){
    if(text!=null){
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        String match = null;
        while(matcher.find()){
            match = matcher.group(groupIndex);
            break;
        }
        return match;           
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you can plug in that pattern like this:

```java
String imageSource = getMatch("<\\s*img\\s*[^>]+src\\s*=\\s*(['\"]?)(.*?)\\1", description, 2);
```

Comment: Okay, i'll try it. One question. Whats groupIndex, and whats that '2' doing in groupIndex ?

Comment: I imported java.util.regex.* but i'm getting " 'RegEx' cannot be resolved " in that first return statement. Never worked with RegEx, kinda clueless now..

Comment: `RegEx` is the class I had those two functions in. `groupIndex` specifies which capture group to return from the pattern.