# How to remove <p/> <p> <br/> <br> in my parse data Dom Parsing

Tags: android, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

hello guys I am having problems with my parse data it seems that this extra letters are also being parse i want them remove

how to do this in my code, i will post below.

here is my xmlparser.java

```
public class XMLParser {

// constructor
public XMLParser() {

}

/**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

/**
 * Getting XML DOM element
 * @param XML string
 * */
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setCoalescing(true);
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    if (dbf.isNamespaceAware()==Boolean.TRUE) {
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(Boolean.FALSE);

    }
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}

/** Getting node value
  * @param elem element
  */
 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE || child.getNodeType() == Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE  ){   
                     return child.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 /**
  * Getting node value
  * @param Element node
  * @param key string
  * */
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
        str = str.replaceAll("<br/>"," \n");
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }

 public final String getElemementValue2 ( Node elem) {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null) {
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()) {
             for ( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ) {
                 if(child.getNodeType() == Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE) {
                     return child.getNodeValue();

                 }
             }
         }
     }


    return "";

 }

 public String getValue3(Element item, String str) {
     NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/",str );
     String ses = this.getElemementValue2(n.item(0));

     String mim =ses.replaceAll("(?s)\\<.*?\\>", " \n");

    return mim;

 }


}
```

here is main.java AndroidXMLParsingActivity

```
public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

// All static variables
static final String URL = "https://news.instaforex.com/news";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_PUBDATE = "pubDate";
static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_PUBDATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUBDATE));
        map.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESCRIPTION));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { KEY_TITLE, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_PUBDATE }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost });

            adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String pubDate = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, title);
            in.putExtra(KEY_PUBDATE, pubDate);
            in.putExtra(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
}
}
```

i just wan to parse these codes here in description and i want to stop the parse data before  this

please look into this [link](https://news.instaforex.com/news) and check description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [How to strip or escape html tags in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502759/how-to-strip-or-escape-html-tags-in-android)

You can use  `Html.fromHtml(stringToEscape).toString();` method to escape the tags whichever you want.

**EDITED:**

Try to pass the values of the pudate & description by getting from the HashMap as i showned below:

> ```
>   @Override
>   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>      setContentView(R.layout.main);
> ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
> XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
> String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
> Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
>
> NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
> // looping through all item nodes <item>
> for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
>     // creating new HashMap
>     HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
>     Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
>     // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
>     map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
>     map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
>     map.put(KEY_PUBDATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUBDATE));
>     map.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESCRIPTION));
>     // adding HashList to ArrayList
>     menuItems.add(map);
> }
>
> // Adding menuItems to ListView
> ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
>         R.layout.list_item,
>         new String[] { KEY_TITLE, KEY_PUBDATE }, new int[] {
>                 R.id.name, R.id.cost });
>
> setListAdapter(adapter);
>
> // selecting single ListView item
> ListView lv = getListView();
> lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
>             int position, long id) {
>         String m_pubDate = menuItems.get(position).get(KEY_PUBDATE).toString();
>     String m_description=menuItems.get(position).get(KEY_DESCRIPTION).toString();
>
> System.out.println("PubDate==>"+m_pubDate+"\n Description===>"+m_description);
>         // Starting new intent
>         Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
>         in.putExtra(KEY_PUBDATE, m_pubDate);
>         in.putExtra(KEY_DESCRIPTION, m_description);
>         startActivity(in);
>     }
>    });
>  }
> ```

I hope it will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks grishu for the reply, can you show me an example base in my codes posted i would really appreciate it thanks

Comment: You can check out here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193525/android-dom-parser-retrieving-image-link-from-description-tag

Comment: I still not working, can you atleast show me how to use that method in my code.. please please

Comment: Try to add where you are getting the response as a string before parsing the data.

Comment: i get it now Grishu and its now working no more html tags for me thanks!!, but i have another problem in my listview i want the title and pubdate only to display, the on second activity  i want title and description to display,, I tried to delete the KEY_DESC in the ListAdapter but not works. Deleting map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC)); too, but doesn't works. any idea?

Comment: Try to access the value from your `HashMap` only as : `String pubDate = menuItems.get(i).get(KEY_PUBDATE).toString();
String description=menuItems.get(i).get(KEY_DESCRIPTION).toString();` and put this values in your intent and access it from the second activity.

Comment: can you show me an example base on my code above, for my reference also, TIA!

Comment: Wow! Grishu you are the MAN!! thanks for helping on this. btw its has error i added final before  ArrayList<HashMap<String, but nontheless it works! thanks for helping me out on this, please keep up helping newbie programmers like, thanks thanks! really appreciate it! god bless you! can add you up in FB or skype?

Comment: I am glad to help you dear . Please vote up the answer . Thanks :)

Comment: btw, im just wandering is there a method to automatically refresh my listview?? because i always need to close and open my application for me to refresh it.. can you hel me again Grishu?

Comment: You can use the `listViewAdapater.notifyDataSetChanged();` method to referesh your listview.

Comment: I think you should post the another question for your queries other than the above question you have posted.

Comment: try with `adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);` before you set the adapter .

Comment: Im getting errors please check my updated codes above i think i did it wrong?

Comment: Try out as `setListAdapter(adapter); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: i just try that i paste the method below setListAdapter(adapter); but still there was error the notifyDateSetChanged it says " The method notifyDateSetChanged() is underfined for the ListAdapter.

Comment: Try with `mMyListView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();`.

Comment: im getting errors on my mMyListView part error says if i want to create a local varialble , class , filed , parameter etc. FYI i still paste that method below the setListAdapter(adapter);

Comment: why does it cannot recognize the method i tried, adapter.setNotifyOnChanged(); and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); both this method i enter below setListAdapter(adapter); but still getting error on method saying "add cast to adapter" please help me out on this Grishu..